# React Navigation: Missing prop at top level component

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a stack navigator set up in the following way

```
const wishlizt = StackNavigator({
        Splash: {screen: SplashScreen},
        SignIn: {screen: SignInScreen},
        SignUp: {screen: SignUpScreen},
        Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen},
        Home: {screen: MainScreenNavigator},
        Chat: {screen: ChatScreen}
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            title: 'Wishlizt',
            header: {
                style: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.bgBrand,
                    elevation: null,
                },
                titleStyle: {
                    color: Colors.lightest
                },
                right: <HeaderRight />
            }
    },
        initialRouteName: 'Splash'

});
```

As you can see I use a component HeaderRight in my header which contains some icons - settings cog, profile, etc.  I want to be able to navigate from those icons' TouchableOpacity onPress method. But the navigation prop 'this.props.navigation' is missing in that component.

The official documentation page has this code sample on how to call navigate on the top level component and recommends using 'ref'

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(SomeAppRouteConfigs);

class App extends React.Component {
  someEvent() {
    // call navigate for AppNavigator here:
    this.navigator && this.navigator.dispatch({ type: 'Navigate', routeName, params });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AppNavigator ref={nav => { this.navigator = nav; }} />
    );
  }
}
```

I am unable to see how this can work in my example.  Can anyone help on this? Thanks

Huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `header` property can be a function as well as an object. When it is a function, the `navigation` object is passed in as the first parameter, it can then be passed to the `HeaderRight` component as a `prop`.

```
navigationOptions: {
            header: (navigation) => {
                return {
                  style: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.bgBrand,
                    elevation: null,
                  },
                  titleStyle: {
                     color: Colors.lightest
                  },
                  right: (<HeaderRight
                             navigation={navigation}
                          />),
               };
           },
},
```

Comment: I have made the suggested fix to the example, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, I am researching why my call isn't working either in react-navigation.  But your braces are messed up in your example.  You have initial route name inside of the navigation options, which might be right, but your indenting shows a whole other story...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "call navigate on the top level" or if you don't have the navigation prop available you can do so as described here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Use ref in the NavigationContainer:

```
// App.js

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { navigationRef } from './RootNavigation';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>{/* ... */}</NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Create RootNavigation.js where you define your dispatches:

```
// RootNavigation.js

import { createNavigationContainerRef } from '@react-navigation/native';

export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(name, params) {
  if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
    navigationRef.navigate(name, params);
  }
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them
```

You can then use your RootNavigation to navigate to the desired screen from anywhere:

```
// any js module
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation.js';

// ...

RootNavigation.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });
```